# Spring Retry is not retrying based on exclude keyword

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

I am using Spring Retry. Earlier, I used `@Retryable(value= Exception.class)` & it worked correctly with `retryAdvice()`. The code correctly retried after getting any kind of exception. Recently, we have a requirement to not retry when MessageTimeoutException is encountered. In all other exceptions, we need to retry.

```java
    @Override
    @Retryable(exclude = MessageTimeoutException.class)
    //@Retryable(exclude = org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException.class)
    public byte[] sendMessage(byte[] message, String guid) {    
        responseBytes = tcpClientGateway.send(message);
        return responseBytes;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(50);
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return retryAdvice;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "emirOutboundChannel")
    public MessageHandler emirOutbound(AbstractClientConnectionFactory emirTcpCachedClientConnectionFactory) {
        TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
        List<Advice> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(retryAdvice());
        tcpOutboundGateway.setAdviceChain(list);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRemoteTimeout(16000);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setRequestTimeout(16000);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setSendTimeout(16000);
        tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(emirTcpCachedClientConnectionFactory);
        return tcpOutboundGateway;
    }
```

Here's the exception that I wish to perform re-try upon. I am wondering what am I missing?

```java
2023-08-16 21:47:54.635 my-project [Thread Id = 351182] ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway:149 - Tcp Gateway exception
org.springframework.integration.MessageTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for response; component: EmirOutbound
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:293) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:234) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:206) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$CallbackImpl.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:166) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.lambda$doInvoke$1(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:86) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:67) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy274.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:153) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:137) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:513) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:486) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:661) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:586) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:553) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:542) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy240.send(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.dao.Emir.service.impl.EmirTcpMessageServiceImpl.sendMessage(EmirTcpMessageServiceImpl.java:32) ~[famulus-claimadj-dao-Emir-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.dao.Emir.service.impl.EmirTcpMessageServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a2bdd82b.invoke(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-dao-Emir-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:329) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:209) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-retry-1.3.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.dao.Emir.service.impl.EmirTcpMessageServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3eb27ea.sendMessage(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-dao-Emir-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.SendMessageToSocketServiceImpl.sendMessageToEmir(SendMessageToSocketServiceImpl.java:35) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.SendMessageToSocketServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$14e5b0a5.invoke(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.common.frameworks.logging.LoggingAspect.logAnnotateClass(LoggingAspect.java:44) ~[famulus-common-frameworks-1.0.0.jar!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.SendMessageToSocketServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$622bf3ca.sendMessageToEmir(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.ProcessB1ServiceImpl.processB1(ProcessB1ServiceImpl.java:227) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.ProcessB1ServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2ffe53b4.invoke(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.common.frameworks.logging.LoggingAspect.logAnnotateClass(LoggingAspect.java:44) ~[famulus-common-frameworks-1.0.0.jar!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.ProcessB1ServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9090be57.processB1(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.ClaimProcessingServiceImpl.processNcpdpRequest(ClaimProcessingServiceImpl.java:94) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.ClaimProcessingServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2ec1bc3.invoke(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.common.frameworks.logging.LoggingAspect.logAnnotateClass(LoggingAspect.java:44) ~[famulus-common-frameworks-1.0.0.jar!/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692) ~[spring-aop-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.logic.services.impl.ClaimProcessingServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ae5417e4.processNcpdpRequest(<generated>) ~[famulus-claimadj-logic-1.0.0.jar!/:1.0.0]
    at com.famulus.claimadj.apis.setup.TcpServerEndpoint.processIncomingMessage(TcpServerEndpoint.java:23) ~[classes!/:1.0.0]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor154.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1101) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:583) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:478) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:356) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:108) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) ~[spring-messaging-5.3.8.jar!/:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:521) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceiveMessage(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:491) ~[spring-integration-core-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.doOnMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:123) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpInboundGateway.onMessage(TcpInboundGateway.java:101) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.sendToChannel(TcpNioConnection.java:406) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNioConnection.run(TcpNioConnection.java:270) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.5.1.jar!/:5.5.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `include`. `exclude` means retry all exceptions except these.

In newer versions; these are deprecated and replaced with `retryFor` and `noRetryFor` respectively.

```java
    /**
     * Exception types that are retryable. Defaults to empty (and, if exclude is also
     * empty, all exceptions are retried).
     * @return exception types to retry
     * @deprecated in favor of {@link #retryFor()}.
     */
    @AliasFor("retryFor")
    @Deprecated
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] include() default {};

    /**
     * Exception types that are retryable. Defaults to empty (and, if noRetryFor is also
     * empty, all exceptions are retried).
     * @return exception types to retry
     * @since 2.0
     */
    @AliasFor("include")
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] retryFor() default {};

    /**
     * Exception types that are not retryable. Defaults to empty (and if include is also
     * empty all exceptions are retried). If includes is empty but exclude is not, all
     * not excluded exceptions are retried
     * @return exception types not to retry
     * @deprecated in favor of {@link #noRetryFor()}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    @AliasFor("noRetryFor")
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] exclude() default {};

    /**
     * Exception types that are not retryable. Defaults to empty (and, if retryFor is also
     * empty, all exceptions are retried). If retryFor is empty but noRetryFor is not, all
     * other exceptions are retried
     * @return exception types not to retry
     * @since 2.0
     */
    @AliasFor("exclude")
    Class<? extends Throwable>[] noRetryFor() default {};
```

Comment: I edited and corrected my question. I apologies for the all the inconvenience caused to you. I intended to mean that we do not have to retry on the exception. Thank you for providing the references. Also, I was able to figure out the issue and corrected the code. I have added my answer and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out the issue. I used [SimpleRetryPolicy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/policy/SimpleRetryPolicy.html)

```java
public SimpleRetryPolicy(int maxAttempts,
                         Map<Class<? extends Throwable>,Boolean> retryableExceptions,
                         boolean traverseCauses)
```

Keeping flag for `traverseCauses` as `true` leads to matching the exception until match is found.

HashMap has the exception which should not be retried and hence it's value i.e. the boolean flag is set to `false`. It simply states that `MessageTimeoutException` should not be retried.

```java
    @Bean
    public RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice() {
        RequestHandlerRetryAdvice retryAdvice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(50);
        Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> mapExceptions = new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>();
        mapExceptions.put(MessageTimeoutException.class, false);
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, mapExceptions, true);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        retryAdvice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
        return retryAdvice;
    }
```

Comment: So, your `@Retryable` has confused us. And I think you have to use `traverseCauses = true`, because in the end of handling that `MessageTimeoutException` is wrapped to other `MessageHandlingException`. I believe we have fixed that at some point since `TcpOutboundGateway` throws this `MessageTimeoutException` as a valid `MessageHandlingException` with all the information, therefore no need in wrapping. Consider to upgrade to the latest version: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn